# How to calculate memory (in bytes) of an Object array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, memory, memory-management

The Question is:

Consider a data type `Planet` with the attributes `String name` and `int moons`. What is the memory footprint (in
bytes) of the array `planets` of `Planet` objects, created and initialized in the following manner?

```
Planet [] planets = new Planet [8];
planets [0] = new Planet (" Mercury ", 0);
planets [1] = new Planet (" Venus ", 0);
planets [2] = new Planet (" Earth ", 1);
planets [3] = new Planet (" Mars " , 2);
planets [4] = new Planet (" Jupiter ", 67);
planets [5] = new Planet (" Saturn ", 62);
planets [6] = new Planet (" Uranus ", 27);
planets [7] = new Planet (" Neptune ", 14);
```

The answer it gives me on my study guide is:

> 24 + 8 × 32 + 56 + 2 × (7 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 7 + 6 + 6 + 7) = 430 bytes

Can someone please explain to me how all those values come together in regards to overhead and the specific memory footprint of the object.

Comment: Well, where do *you* think they come from? (Note that the 7, 5, 5, 4 etc are wrong for the strings you've put there). But also, we don't know the definition of the `Planet` class, so it's impossible to say how much memory it takes up.

Comment: It's difficult to reliably calculate memory footprint because it can vary by JVM and configuration. I got 712 bytes with my own estimation method.

Comment: If your *study guide* asks this question, then it has explained about object overhead, and array overhead, so maybe you just need to (re-)read the guide, and you'll find the answer.

Comment: I was told that "Each planet object takes up 32 bytes (16 bytes of overhead + 8 bytes for the string name + 4 bytes for the int moon count + 4 bytes of padding)."